# Почему IS NULL так медленно работает?

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день.
Есть запрос вида:

```sql
SELECT `call_call`.*, `call_operation`.`id_operation`
FROM `call_call`
LEFT JOIN `call_operation` ON `call_operation`.`id_call_operation` = `call_call`.`id_call`
WHERE `active_call` = '1' AND `id_operation` IS NULL
```

Explain:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE call_call ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 109590 Using where
1 SIMPLE call_operation ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 5717 Using where; Not exists
```

Мне нужно получить все записи основной таблицы и узнать для каких из них нет записей в таблице подчиненной.
Выполняется этот запрос за 0.3568 сек, получаем чуть больше 500 записей.

Немного изменив условие:

```sql
SELECT `call_call`.*, `call_operation`.`id_operation`
FROM `call_call`
LEFT JOIN `call_operation` ON `call_operation`.`id_call_operation` = `call_call`.`id_call`
WHERE `active_call` = '1' AND (`id_operation`>0)
```

Explain:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE call_operation ALL PRIMARY NULL NULL NULL 5717 Using where
1 SIMPLE call_call eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 recaller.call_operation.id_call_operation 1 Using where
```

Получаем запрос, который делает все в точности до наоборот, извлекает только те записи из главной, у которой есть связные записи с подчиненной.
Выполняется этот запрос 0.0074 сек, получаем чуть больше 400 записей.

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите почему такая большая разница, и в какую сторону копать, чтобы оптимизировать первый запрос?
Заранее спасибо.

---

**Эксперименты:**

```sql
WHERE NOT (`id_operation`>0)                /* возвращает 0 строк */
WHERE (`id_operation`<1)                    /* возвращает 0 строк */
WHERE NOT EXIST `id_operation`              /* возвращает error */
WHERE CONVERT(`id_operation`,UNSIGNED) = 0  /* возвращает 0 строк */
WHERE (`id_operation`*1) = 0                /* возвращает 0 строк */
WHERE `id_operation` = NULL                 /* возвращает 0 строк */
WHERE `id_operation` NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'  /* возвращает 0 строк */
```

---

**SHOW CREATE TABLE `call_call`**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `call_call` (
`id_call` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 ...
 `reason_call` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `active_call` int(2) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id_call`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=127271 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE `call_operation`**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `call_operation` (
 `id_operation` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `id_call_operation` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 ...
 `result_operation` varchar(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id_operation`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5782 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

---

[Похожая проблема: http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=1&tid=111883](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=1&tid=111883), но советов по делу нет, человека не поняли.

Comment: А не пробовали использовать explain?

Comment: Пробовал. До вашего совета, правда не пробовал их сравнивать. Я так понял, что скорость падает из-за того, что во втором случае possible_keys - PRIMARY, а в первом possible_keys - NULL, то есть не используется индекс.
Но тогда остается второй вопрос, как мне использовать индекс, если конструкции вида:  WHERE NOT (`id_operation`>0), WHERE (`id_operation`<1) возвращают 0 строк. WHERE NOT EXIST `id_operation` возвращает error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите, есть ли  у Вас индекс на поле `id_operation`?

Насколько мне позволяет телепатия, у Вас есть ключи (и индексы) по `call_operation`.`id_call_operation` и `call_call`.`id_call` - по которым Вы и делаете JOIN, и о чем Вам и говорит `EXPLAIN` в разделе `possible_keys`.

И, вообще, для полноты картины можно было б структуру базы показать подробнее (порседством `SHOW CREATE` например)

Успехов!

Comment: Добавил show create.
Да, join делаю по ключам.
Задача сократилась до: "Как выбрать несуществующие связные записи не используя IS NULL"

Comment: Видимо не правильно понял вашу "телепатию". Если бы понял - сразу бы проставил индекс на id_call_operation. А так увы, полсуток вычеркнул из жизни. Все равно спасибо.

Comment: @Город, постараюсь писать более конкретно! Рад что помогло, успехов!

Answer (score 0):

`` WHERE NOT (`id_operation`>0) `` это `` WHERE (`id_operation`<=0) `` и в случае когда `id_operation` равен null будет всегда false, а отрицательных или равных 0 `id_operation` у вас нет. По этой же причине `` WHERE (`id_operation`<1) `` тоже вернет 0 строк.

Очень сомневаюсь, но попробуйте поставить скобки вокруг `(id_operation IS NULL)`

Comment: "попробуйте поставить скобки" - К сожалению прироста скорости не дало :( Нет никаких "синонимичных" способов, помимо IS NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с вопросом мой коллега.
IS NULL никуда не делся, и дело было не в нем, я не туда копал.

Если на поле `id_call_operation` в таблице `call_operation` проставить индекс, то занимаемое время мгновенно падает до 0.0012 сек.

Вопрос закрыт. Всем учавствовавшим спасибо.

Comment: про индекс писал SAABeilin

Comment: Да, его ответ и отметил как правильный, откомментил.